# Install Prettier - ESLint: how to install?

Tags: reactjs

Youtube video (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=J3PH1EOPKhU) recommends Prettier - ESLint for VS Code.

Visual Studio Marketplace does not have it.

I found Github: https://github.com/prettier/prettier-eslint

But, I do not understand install instructions.

Answer (score 1):

You should know these things to understand:

- eslint: A set of conventions to make your code consistent.
- prettier: A tool help you to format your code effortless.
- prettier-eslint: help prettier to format your code using setting from eslint.

`eslint` and `prettier` are tools that available to use via CLI. Something like `eslint --fix` or such.

To integrate prettier with VS code, you should also need to use the plugin to make it work on VS code: https://github.com/prettier/prettier-vscode

Comment: Your explanation is a definition of what these things are. You also re-state the link that I provided. How do I install it?